# VS2012 error using trailing return type with decltype and variadic template

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I get this error when compiling some code using Visual Studio (Nov '12 CTP):

```
1>c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\main.cpp(19): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type locked_call(Lockable &,Callable,Args &&...)'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'std::mutex'
1>          'main::<lambda_d4c412a6f5bd8d382f54c74dc3b1ff5d>'
1>          ''
```

Here is a short example of my function:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <utility>

template <class Lockable, class Callable, typename... Args>
auto locked_call(Lockable &mtx, Callable fn, Args &&... args)
    -> decltype(fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    std::lock_guard<Lockable> hold(mtx);
    return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;

    locked_call(mtx, [&] {
    });
}
```

So my question is: Why does this not compile? Trailing return types, variadic templates and decltype are all supported by VS11, yet the compiler appears to be unable to get the result type of the function call.

Comment: Looks like compiler bug http://liveworkspace.org/code/3HPtzW$0

Comment: This is most definitely a bug in VC11. Your code is correct in all respects, and all major compilers on LWS [compile this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/GmHGy$48).

Comment: It also works using clang, so it might be a bug in VS11.
Do you guys know any workarounds?